# OpenCV How to rotate cv::RotatedRect?

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I apply some transformation (e.g. rotation) to a `cv::rotatedRect`?
Tried using `cv::warpAffine` but won't work, as it is supposed to be applied to cv::Mat...

Answer (score 3):

You can control rotation translation and scale directly using the internal variables `angle`, `center` & `size` see [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rotatedrect).

More general transformations requires getting the vertices using `points()` and manipulating them using for example `cv::warpAffine`but once doing that you will no longer have a `cv::rotatedRect` (by definition)

Comment: true, but what about the remaining vars? must i not change them?

Comment: You can control rotation translation and scale directly using the internal variables. more general transformations require manipulating the four vertices ( points() ) but you won't have a rotatedRect anymore...

Answer (score 3):

If you are planing to do complex operations like `affine` or `perspective`, you should deal with the points of the `rotated rect` and the result may be quad shape not a rectangle.

cv::warpAffine works for images. you should use [cv::Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20perspectiveTransform(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20m)) and [cv::Perspectivetransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20perspectiveTransform(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20m))

They take array of points and produced array of points.

**Example:**

```
cv::RotatedRect rect;
//fill rect somehow
cv::Point2f rect_corners[4];
rect.points(rect_corners);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> rect_corners_transformed(4);
cv::Mat M;
//fill M with affine transformation matrix
cv::transform(std::vector<cv::Point2f>(std::begin(rect_corners), std::end(rect_corners)), rect_corners_transformed, M);
// your transformed points are in rect_corners_transformed
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Create a new rectangle.

I don't know if it will help you, but I solved a similar problem by creating a new rectangle and ignoring the old one. In other words, I calculated the new angle, and then assigned it and the values of the old rectangle (the center point and the size) to the new rectangle:

```
RotatedRect newRotatedRectangle(oldRectangle.center, oldRectangle.size, newAngle);
```